# Using String.isEmpty() with ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android

So, I have this line of code in an Android Project:

```
x.select("p").first().getElementsByTag("img").isEmpty()
```

And Eclipse is giving me this error: "Call requires API level 9 (current min is 8): java.lang.String#isEmpty".

I don't suppose there's something wrong with it, because I have that exact same piece a few lines down, and Eclipse doesn't say anything. And, if I clean the project that error disappears, and the app works just fine.

But if I change anything and save it, there comes the error again, and so I have clean it. Again.

I know there are other alternatives that I could use, or just change the min API to 9, but I would like to understand (and fix if possible) why is this happening.

Comment: Hmm, whose method is `getElementsByTag()` exactly? It looks like [Element](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/Element.html), but that doesn't return String (but NodeList).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TextUtils.isEmpty(string)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) to check if a String is null or empty.

Comment: OP wrote: "I know there are other alternatives that I could use [...] but I would like to understand why is this happening."

Comment: @Jonik I think it's pretty clear why it is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `String.isEmpty()` was introduced in API level 9 with Android (see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty%28%29)). On a lower device it will in fact crash with a `NoSuchMethodException`.

Just use

```
String.trim().equals("")
```